# Can i create a drop down list using SWT, in Eclipse - RCP based java application?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

Every list item should have an image and a text. So far I have tried using ListViewer, ComboViewer and TableViewer. My requirement is to have a dropdown list and every list item should be have an image and a text.

Comment: A drop-down from what? A menu? A button? In any case there isn't a simple why to do this, you would have to construct a temporary shell to hold the drop down. You could look at the source of `CCombo` which displays a drop down using a shell and `List`. Or may look at Eclipse Nebula [TableCombo](https://eclipse.dev/nebula/widgets/tablecombo/tablecombo.php)

Comment: Earlier I was using a combo to display some text but now I want to display images as well to differentiate between same named options. I want to replace this combo

Comment: Look at TableCombo then